Reconnect Epic Games Launcher to already downloaded games?
I've changed my OS from Windows 10 to Windows 11 (triple booting with Kubuntu), and want to run the games I have on my games drive (D:), for example I have Fortnite installed in D:/Epic Games/Fortnite. I've installed Epic Games launcher, but there doesn't appear to be any settings to tell it where the games are located so I can launch them?
For example, their help says to reinstall the whole library, which is 100s of GB, maybe a TB of games which are all already on my drive just in a different folder!
Epic also suggest starting an install, then moving game files into that folder, but this doesn't work for me. I changed the existing Epic folder's name to D:/Epic Games1, then downloaded 1% of Fortnite to D:/Epic Games (without "1"), then quit Epic's launcher, then moved the downloaded files to the original folder, renamed it back to just "Epic Games". So now Epic knows to install to D:/Epic Games and all my library of downloaded games are in there ... but on launching Epic Games Launcher it continues, then "verifies", then just starts downloading the game from 1%.
I can't believe that Epic are so inept that they can't allow changing a simple folder string in their config files so you don't have to download all of your games again? How can I fix this so the launcher knows the games are there already?
I tried launching using an .exe file (eg. GenshinImpact/launcher.exe) from the games that are downloaded, but it opened the Epic Games Launcher library screen and then did nothing. Some games - GodlikeBurger, TheStanleyParable - did run however, but they're not then added to the launcher.
Many thanks.
FWIW in Steam you just add the folder with the games as a library location, it recognises the games and you can play them straight away. That's what I was hoping Epic Games Launcher would do.

Try again, but follow the directions. Use the existing download location, pause the download early as you did, but preferably copy the install data rather than move it because "this may not work with all games". And delete the .egstore file mentioned, as that is likely internal data about what to download and how much was downloaded (but must not be a full manifest as Steam uses, or it'd need editing instead of nuking it).
